# ImportError: No module named... on Jupyter Notebook using docker

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I am running a project using docker on Windows 10 and Jupyter notebook (my apologies for not being precise with terms but I am quite new to all this). I have to import some modules that are stored locally on my PC but when I do so on Jupyter I get the error `ImportError: No module named`. I do not understand why some of the modules are loaded correctly and others are not. I checked my local folders on Windows and I saw that all of them have the empty `__init__.py` file.
Here is my code:

```
from abc.config import getConfig
from abc.log_util import getLogger
from abc.services.rcp.library import indb
```

The first two lines work properly, with the third one I get the `ImportError`. However, I do have some directories called `abc/services/rcp/library` on my PC.
If I run the command on the Jupyter notebook

```
import sys
sys.path
```

I get the output

```
['',
 '/mnt/shared/abc-services-rcp',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/root/.ipython']
```

so the `abc-services-rcp` path seems to be there. Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue, I'll post the answer in case anyone has my same issue in the future. Apparently the module `abc.services.rcp` was not installed. I found it out by executing the command `pip list` and I saw that the module was not there. It was enough to execute on jupyter a `pip install abc.services.rcp` and wait until the installation of the module was finished, then restart the kernel and run the `import` code again.